# PDFTron Web Viewer HTTP 404 error on ASP.NET MVC Razor View on using @model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdftron

PDFTron Web Viewer not displayed on ASP.NET Razor View on using @model. I receive a HTTP 404 - Not Found error. Without using @model, and in the Controller removing **return View(doc);** and using **return View();** the PDFTron Web Viewer displays the XOD document but on using @model the XOD Viewer is not displayed.

Razor View is as follows. Removing the **@model XODViewer.DataModel.Document** and changing **return View(doc);** to **return View();** makes it work. I need to bind the View to the model class to access the properties of my model on the View.

Does PDFTron not support displaying the Web Viewer control on MVC Razor View bound to a model?

```
@model XODViewer.DataModel.Document

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Document";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/WebViewer.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #viewer {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>

<script>
        $(function () {
            var docName = 'GettingStarted.xod';
            var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
            var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
                path: 'lib',
                type: 'html5',
                documentType: "xod",
                initialDoc: "lib/GettingStarted.xod",
                config: '',
                streaming: false,
                enableAnnotations: false,
                enableOfflineMode: false,
                enableReadOnlyMode: true
            }, viewerElement);
        });
</script>

<h2>Document</h2>


<div id="viewer" style="overflow: auto;width:100%;">
</div>
```

[image: HTTP 404 Not Found Error]

Comment: do you have some path like this: Documents/lib/html5/ReaderController.html in your solution???

Comment: @ImanSalehi : There is no explicit path defined by me as : **Documents/lib/html5/ReaderController.html**. This is a file used by the PDFTron Web Viewer control and is already present as a part of my VS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has started working now with a relative path with the View now bound to a model class.

```
@model XODViewerApp.Model.Document

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Document";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/WebViewer.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #viewer {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>

<script>
        $(function () {
            var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
            var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
                path: 'lib',
                type: 'html5',
                documentType: "xod",
                initialDoc: "lib/GettingStarted.xod",
                config: '',
                streaming: false,
                enableAnnotations: false,
                enableOfflineMode: false,
                enableReadOnlyMode: true
            }, viewerElement);
        });
</script>

<h2>Document</h2>

<div id="viewer" style="overflow: auto;width:100%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lib` parameter in the `WebViewer` constructor is what you use to point `WebViewer` to its library, in particular the `html5` subfolder.

I would try setting that parameter to an absolute path, instead of a relative path, as it appears the relative one is not working, as your 404 error message indicates it cannot find `lib/html5/ReaderControl.html`

Comment: Setting a absolute path like `path:'D:\Projects\XodWebViewerApp\XODWebViewerApp\lib\html5\ReaderControl.html'` doesn't display the PDFTron WebViewer control at all. Also, when this is deployed to IIS or Azure, have to provide a relative path. Can't use absolute path for `ReaderControl.html` file in this case.

Also why WebViewer control with relative path for `ReaderControl.htlml` file is working with View not binded to a model class and doesn't with with View binded to a model class? Is this a bug in PDFTron WebViewer control?

Comment: It has started working now with a relative path. Not sure if there is some bug in PDFTron Web Viewer control which was producing HTTP 404 Not found error and suddenly it has started working with the View now bound to a model class.